# Why are my threaded MySQLdb queries in Python slower than the same non-threaded queries?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

I am building a threaded class to run MySQL queries using Python and MySQLdb.  I don't understand why running these queries threaded is slower than running them non-threaded.  Here's my code to show what I'm doing.

First, here's the non-threaded function.

```
def testQueryDo(query_list):

    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    q_list = query_list
    for each in q_list:
        cursor.execute(each)
        results = cursor.fetchall()

    db.close()
```

Here's my threaded class:

```
class queryThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

        self.db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name')
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def run(self):
        cur_query = self.queue.get()
        self.cursor.execute(cur_query)
        results = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.db.close()
        self.queue.task_done()
```

And here's the handler:

```
def queryHandler(query_list):
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    for query in query_list:
        queue.put(query)

    total_queries = len(query_list)
    for query in range(total_queries):
        t = queryThread(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    queue.join()
```

I'm not sure why this threaded code is running slower.  What's interesting is that if I use the same code, only do something simple like addition of numbers, the threaded code is *significantly* faster.

I understand that I must be missing something completely obvious, however any support would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting N threads, each of which creates its own connection to MySQL, and you're using a synchronous queue to deliver the queries to the threads. Each thread is blocking on `queue.get()` (acquiring an exclusive lock) to get a query, then creating a connection to the database, and then calling `task_done()` which lets the next thread proceed.  So while thread 1 is working, N-1 threads are doing nothing.  This overhead of lock acquire/release, plus the addditional overhead of serially creating and closing several connections to the database adds up.

Comment: Also CPython only allows one thread to run at a time (due to the GIL) so even if...

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that they were running simultaneously!  Thank you samplebias!  Would it be more efficient if I used multiple processes to fork each query, or is there a better/more efficient way to do it with threading that I'm missing?

Comment: Really depends on your application, but some things which will improve performance of the your example above: use a smaller threadpool and deliver several queries to each thread instead of one, have each thread reuse its database connection for multiple queries. If you decide to use `fork`, you could try the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module to make it easier to communicate with your subprocesses.

Comment: It sounds like if I want to run multiple queries at the same time (which is my goal - to make if faster), that multiprocessing is the way to go, otherwise I have to deal with the GIL in threading.  Unless, I'm missing something, and there's actually a way to do this with the threading module.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Python threads must synchronize on the GIL, so within a single Python process two threads cannot execute bytecode concurrently. However, the MySQLdb native code yields the GIL before it begins a blocking operation (connecting, executing a query, reading a result set), so other Python threads can make progress. So if you use Python threads you will have true concurrency while inside certain MySQLdb native routines.

Comment: Here is a link [explaining threading and the GIL](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock)

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I've got it now!

Comment: @mudda This answer is WRONG. Queue.get() does NOT acquire an exclusive lock until "task_done" is called. That is baloney. It is possible MySQL is your bottleneck when multiple queries across the same tables. While MySQLdb does release the GIL around certain operations, it also does significant work while holding the GIL, causing GIL contention and may also explain the slowdown.

Comment: @mudda @aaa90210 I cant believe this is the accepted answer. The command `queue.get` ensures that an item from the queue is popped off in a synchronous manner. Thats it. It has nothing to do with task_done. You'll have to debug a bit further to figure out why your queries are taking a long time. And yes, some optimisations can be made here regarding the non-reuse of db connections